# how to make the table not having <thead> header fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table without thead tag.

```js
    $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
       var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
       $(column).hide();
    });
    
    $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
       var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
       $(column).toggle();
      })
```

```html
  

 

<style>
.scroll-table {
  
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
overflow-x:scroll;
}
.scroll-table thead {
  display: block;
}
.scroll-table thead th {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.scroll-table tbody {
  display: block;
  height: 262px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 450px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 150px;
}
</style>


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <p style="margin-left:15px;"> Additional information select below: </p>
           <p style="display:inline; margin-left:15px">
         <input type="checkbox" name="vendor"  />Vendor Details
         <input type="checkbox" name="ONX"  />Quantity Level
         <input type="checkbox" name="Cost" /> Cost Detail
        <!-- <li><input type="checkbox" name="d"  />d</li> -->
             
              </p>
        <table id="testTable" class="scroll-table" >
            <caption ><u><h2 >ITEM ONHAND QUANTITIES & GOODS IN TRANSACTION</h2></u></caption>
             
           
            <thead>
<tr class="header" style="background-color: #3f91bd;color:white;
            /* position: absolute;
            width: 83%; */">
            <th class="first">ITEM CODE</th>
        <th class="second">ITEM NAME</th>
        <th class="third">UNIT</th>
        <th class="headcol">ON HAND QTY</th>
          <th class="headcol">GIT</th>
           <th class="headcol">ATP</th>
           <th class="ONX" name="ONX">ONX LOW LMT</th>
            <th class="ONX"  name="ONX">ONX HIGH LMT</th>
             <th class="ONX"  name="ONX">ONX RE-ORDER-LEVEL</th>
              <th class="Cost">AVG COST</th> 
           <th class="Cost" >LAST PO PRICE</th>
           <th class="vendor" name="vendor">V_CODE</th>
           <th class="vendor">MAIN_VENDOR</th>
           <th class="vendor">VENDOR_TYPE</th>
           <th class="vendor">Vendor Mx LEAD TIM</th>
         </tr>

    </thead>  
    <tbody style="border: 1px solid green; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll; height:400px; width:850px"> 
             <tr>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td class="ONX">aaa</td>
            <td class="ONX">aaa</td>
            <td class="ONX">aaa</td>
            <td class="Cost">aaa</td>
            <td class="Cost">aaa</td>
            <td class="vendor">aaa</td>
            <td class="vendor">aaa</td>
            <td class="vendor">aaa</td>
            <td class="vendor">aaa</td></tr>
    
            <tr><td>bbb</td><td>bbb</td><td>bbb</td><td>bbb</td><td>bbb</td><td>bbb</td><td class="ONX">bbb</td><td class="ONX">bbb</td><td class="ONX" >bbb</td><td class="Cost">bbb</td><td class="Cost">bbb</td><td class="vendor">bbb</td><td class="vendor">bbb</td><td class="vendor">bbb</td><td class="vendor">bbb</td></tr>
```

Here the columns belong to class vendor, ONX and cost will be displayed on the basis of checkbox selection.

It's very big table generated dynamically. so I want to make its header fixed. I have tried with different ways like adding header thead which fails to show proper alignment and also used few plugins.  one or the other way it fails.

Can any one suggest me how could i make th content fixed ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu

Comment: @NewbeeDev my table doesn't have thead. so i ts not working. i checked it already.

Comment: Extract that first row via Javascript and put it in a seperate table above your original table. Then wrap both tables in divs. Use position: fixed on first div. Then wrap both divs in another div, set max-height: 100vh; overflow: auto;.

Comment: @DeepakYadav It's a great sollution for the table having <thead> . But in my table there is no <thead> . I have tried adding <thead> but all the <tbody> content will be grouped under first header and rest of headers go out of the table. So it won work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches. One with pure CSS and other using jQuery.

```css
.scroll-table {
  width: 450px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.scroll-table thead {
  display: block;
}
.scroll-table thead th {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.scroll-table tbody {
  display: block;
  height: 262px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 450px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table scroll-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>And Repeat 1</td>
      <td>And Repeat 2</td>
      <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>And Repeat 1</td>
      <td>And Repeat 2</td>
      <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>And Repeat 1</td>
      <td>And Repeat 2</td>
      <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>And Repeat 1</td>
      <td>And Repeat 2</td>
      <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>And Repeat 1</td>
      <td>And Repeat 2</td>
      <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>And Repeat 1</td>
      <td>And Repeat 2</td>
      <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>And Repeat 1</td>
      <td>And Repeat 2</td>
      <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>And Repeat 1</td>
      <td>And Repeat 2</td>
      <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>And Repeat 1</td>
      <td>And Repeat 2</td>
      <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>And Repeat 1</td>
      <td>And Repeat 2</td>
      <td>And Repeat 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>Even More Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>End of Cell Content 1</td>
      <td>End of Cell Content 2</td>
      <td>End of Cell Content 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

or if you want the jQuery approach.
Check my codepen:
[Codepen for Responsive tables using jQuery](http://codepen.io/happy2deepak/pen/XKXKaq)

Comment: Thanks @Deepak Yadav. Please run my updated code. So that you can make out the issue when i add thead. And suggest me any solution to fix it if you can please.

Comment: @safoorasafu can't customize it for your code. Running out of time; Go through the code once, you can get it altered as per your requirement.

Comment: all these kinds of solution I already tried before and came here as I dint find the solution. Because adding thead is the problem for me.

Comment: Add a bounty,  someone will fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```css
table,tr,th,td{
border:1px solid #dddddd;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:300px">
<tr height="30">
  <th width="30%">He</th>
  <th width="30%">ad</th>
  <th width="40%">er</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<div style="width:317px; overflow:auto; height:100px;">
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr height="30">
    <td width="30%">td</td>
    <td width="30%">td</td>
    <td width="40%">td</td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="30">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="30">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="30">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="30">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr height="30">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ramu. when i add thead  all theaders are overflowing(run my code , i updated). do you know the reason/solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a css to set the width of  tag like:

```
<th width="70%">
```

or

```
<th width="50px">
```